# Regex filter does not do an exact match

Tags: jquery, regex

I am using the the following regex to filter

```
 return this.href.match(/goto.com|xyz.com|loop.com/g);
```

However if there's a url called dogoto.com, that too gets filtered. How can I change my Regex to disallow that?

http://jsfiddle.net/wQYuz/7/

Comment: What exactly do you WANT the regexp to match or not to match?

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VkAP8/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `\b` (a word boundary) on both sides of it.

```
return this.href.match(/\b(goto\.com|xyz\.com|loop\.com)\b/g);
```

Here's a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wQYuz/9/

Comment: it works for your test case but it needs brackets around the alternation or it only fixes `dogoto.com`. `doxyz.com` and `doloop.com` will still match when they shouldn't.

Comment: because the demo does not contain doxyz.com. Your regex says \bgoto.com OR xyz.com OR loop.com\b. Also as Pietu states, the .s need to be escaped or xyzHcom also matches.

Comment: Didn't even notice you were switched them up. Good point! I've updated my code.

Comment: @BillCriswell Can you explain the Regex?

Comment: I do `\.` because just a `.` will match any character. I do `\b` for the word boundaries, so it's like a white space, start of string or new line from what I best understand. I actually thought about it a bit and came up wit this which would be easier to manage for you. http://jsfiddle.net/wQYuz/10/

Comment: Thanks @BillCriswell!! Can you add some comments in the code itself? I am a designer turned dev, so comments would help :)

Comment: just found a bug. What if I have something like http://me.xyz.com. It should get highligted but it does not

Comment: Quick update. Thought it was better to be explicit about what you wanted to highlight. http://jsfiddle.net/wQYuz/13/

Answer (score 1):

`^` matches the start of the string. You could do that:

```
return this.href.match(/^(goto\.com|xyz\.com|loop\.com)/g);
```

Or, you could match any non-alphanumeric character there:

```
return this.href.match(/\Wgoto\.com|\Wxyz\.com|\Wloop\.com/g);
```

Also, you might want to escape your dots (done here) because otherwise the dot matches any character, not just itself.

Comment: How's this different from a boundary \b as Bill suggested

Comment: @KayKay This one does basically the same thing but in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
/\b(goto\.com|xyz\.com|loop\.com)\b/g
```

`\b` matches at the start/end of a word. It needs brackets around the words otherwise doxyz.com and doloop.com would still match.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wQYuz/7/)

Comment: ^ at the start as some have suggested rules out everything except a URL at the start of the line